# Runing laravel from another pc without artisan serve css and js not working

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, xampp

i have a trouble when i want to acces my local project from another pc, I've success run laravel without artisan serve and then the css and js is working well on server pc, but when i trying to acces project from another pc

```
192.168.x.x/projectname
```

css and js is not working?

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running your Laravel application using below command.

```
php artisan serve --host YOUR_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS --port PORT_NUMBER
```

Then try to access your application from another PC.

```
http://YOUR_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS:PORT_NUMBER
```